# How to check a file is locked in MFC?

Tags: mfc

I am using MFC CFile.

In windows OS in my application I am locking the file by opening the file with share deny access.

In the same application or process I have to check whether the file is locked or not?

Right now, the only way I know is opening the file and checking GetLastError().

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Are you locking a file region or do you just open the file with normal deny share access?

Comment: @Barmak, I just open the file with normal deny share access.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the file first. If the file exists and is already open without share access, you get a sharing violation 
`CFileException::sharingViolation`.

See [`CFileException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfileexception-class?view=vs-2019) for possible values of `CFileException::m_cause`

Example:

```
UINT open_flag = CFile::modeReadWrite | CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeNoTruncate;
CFileException ex;
if(file.Open(filename, open_flag, &ex))
{
    //success
}
else 
{
    if(ex.m_cause == CFileException::fileNotFound)
    {
        //file doesn't exit
    }
    else if(ex.m_cause == CFileException::sharingViolation)
    {
        //file exists and is locked
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

while reading a data from csv file, I got also same errors

In my case,

1. existed csv file with the same name was open. So, I closed that csv file and it was Okay.

later was the same issue again.

2. this time, I wrote inappropriate mode while creating
   so I changed this code

`file.Open(fileName, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeReadWrite)`

to

`file.Open(fileName, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite)`